# Topological space +metrization + homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\delta)$ be a metric space,$(Y,\tau)$ a topological space.Assume that $(X,\delta)$ is homeomorphic to $(Y,\tau)$ .

Is $(Y,\tau)$ metrisable ,i.e there is a metric that induces the topology on $Y$.

If false ,can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $(Y,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\phi : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $d^*(y_1,y_2) := d(\phi^{-1}(y_1), \phi^{-1}(y_2))$, for $y_1,y_2 \in Y$ defines a metric on $Y$ that generates the correct topology. That is, $(Y,d^*)$ is a metric space with topology $\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

A homeomorphism tells you that two topological spaces are the "same". So, yes intuitively $(Y,\tau)$ should have a metric space structure as well.

To get this structure, let $\varphi:Y\to X$ be our homeomorphism. Define a metric $d$ on $Y$ by $d(y_1,y_2)=\delta(\varphi(y_1),\varphi(y_2))$. Try to show that this is indeed a metric on $Y$.